# How to implement Streaming Input with Subprocesses in PYTHON?

Tags: python, subprocess

Since `input` and `raw_input()` stop the program from running anymore, I want to use a subprocess to run this program...

```
while True: print raw_input()
```

and get its output.

This is what I have as my reading program:

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen('python subinput.py', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE) 
while True:
    output=process.stdout.read(12)
    if output=='' and process.poll()!=None:
        break
    if output!='':
        sys.stdout.write(output)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

When I run this, the subprocess exits almost as fast as it started. How can I fix this?

Comment: maybe you just need to use standard pipes?  "$ python subinput.py | python otherscript.py".  You can handle stdin input with the fileinput module.   But, if you already have subinput.py why not import that directly and call as a normal function?

Comment: @monkut: raw_input() blocks, that is, it stops the program until it recieves input

Comment: So why do you want to do this?  There may be a better way to do what you want.  At the moment, given the example, it makes little sense to run "while True: print raw_input()" as a separate process.

Comment: What I generally want is streaming input, input without my program completely stopping everytime it needs input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it won't work this way.

You assume, that `subprocess` will attach your console (your special
case of `stdin`). This does not work, the module only has two
options for specifying that: `PIPE` and `STDOUT`.

When nothing is specified, the subprocess won't be able to use
the corresponding stream - it's output will go nowhere or it will
receive no input. The `raw_input()` ends because of EOF.

The way to go is to have your input in the "main" program, 
and the work done in a subprocess.

EDIT:

Here's an example in `multiprocessing`

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
import time

def child(conn):
    while True:
        print "Processing..."
        time.sleep(1)
        if conn.poll(0):
            output = conn.recv()
            print output
        else:
            print "I got nothing this time"

def parent():
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
    p = Process(target=child, args=(child_conn,))
    p.start()
    while True:
        data = raw_input()
        parent_conn.send(data)
    # p.join() - you have to find some way to stop all this...
    # like a specific message to quit etc.


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent()
```

You of course need to make it more robust by finding a way too stop
this cooperation. In my example both processes are in the same file, 
but you may organize it differently.

This example works on Linux, you may have some problems with pipes on Windows,
but it should be altogether solvable.

The "Processing" is the part where you want to do something else, not just
wait for the data from the parent.

Comment: How would I send the input from my main program to my subprocess?

Comment: I edited my answer to show a rudimentary example. You may also take a look at multiprocessing.Queue for an even more high-level communication mechanism, where the queue is notified, that some "task" was finished.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that subprocesses are not directly hooked up to `stdout` and `stdin`, and therefore cannot receive keyboard input.  Presumably raw_input() is throwing an exception.

If this is a practical issue and not an experiment, I recommend you use a library such as curses or pygame to handle your input.  If you're experimenting and want to do it yourself, then I suppose you'll have to look at threads instead of subprocesses, though this is a fairly complex thing to try to do so you're certain to run into other issues.

Answer (score 0):

Well, try different architecture. You can use `zeromq`.

1. Producer produces all the items(here output which to be sent via stdout) and broadcasted via `zmq`.
2. Consumer should listen to the port no which is being broadcasted by the producer and process them accordingly.

Here is the Example [http://code.saghul.net/implementing-a-pubsub-based-application-with](http://code.saghul.net/implementing-a-pubsub-based-application-with%5d)

`Note`

Use `gevent` or `multiprocessing` to spawn these process.

You will have `master` program which takes care of spawning `producer` and `consumer`